# Visual studio code: ignore leading ">>>" in python examples

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

In VS Code, is there any way to run a Python source line in terminal (`shift+Enter`), ignore leading `>>>`?

I heard some other editors have such functionality as one of their built-in features (e.g., IPython). In the case of VS Code, do you have any suggestions for set-ups or extensions?

Comment: I think some sites with such python code block examples has the ability to collapse it so that the `>>>` is not present, making it easier to copy/paste.

Comment: I think that when you run python in vscode it comes directly from your computer so you cant change the ">>>" in vscode. in some other editors the shell comes directly from the application, letting it be changed inside of the editor. im not sure you can change the shell in vscode because of this. Why would you want to run in the shell anyways if you use VSCode?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you mean is ti run it in interactive mode, correct me if I am wrong.
 `CTRL + SHIFT + T` and then type
 `run current file in interactive window`.

Comment: CTRL + SHIFT + T opens the last file, so that isnt necessary. basically, just open the file you want to execute,right click, and select run current file in interactive window.

Answer (score 0):

When you `shift+Enter` in your python script, VSCode deliver your line to the terminal which run python in interactive mode. It means, removing leading prompt string is not the matter of VSCode, but the terminal or python program itself.

The leading prompt string(`>>>` and `...`) is defined in `sys` package. If you want to remove it, try this:

```py
Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug 13 2019, 15:17:50) 
[Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.ps1, sys.ps2 = '', ''
```

ps. I still can't find the way to configure this as default setting in VSCode.